# How to bring Ample guitar onto FL studio piano roll?

Tags: daw, strumming, fl-studio

I have Ample guitar M II lite.
I created a strumming pattern in the guitar plugin, and I want to 'bring' that strumming pattern onto my piano roll and play it with the song. I can't figure out how to do that so please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The notes that the Ample Guitar plugin provides for patterns and chords are not accurate to FL Studio. They are off by two octaves.

| Function | Ample Plugin Notes | FL Studio Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patterns | C3 - D#4 | C5 - D#6 |
| Chords | C1 - B2 | C3 - B4 |

It seems that you can add two to the Ample plugin's octave to find the correct FL Studio octave.

I myself didn't discover this.

Answer (score 1):

Just put root note to C3, then draw notes as AGM did say.

1. Put Root note to C3
2. Turn on the strum mode button
3. In piano roll, draw note C3(for play SEQ1), and here you have 24 chords to play from C1 to B2.